Book about a prototype robot that dies every time it's shut down
I saw this once, in paperback in a bookstore in the early 1990s.
The book's blurb was that the robot was a prototype and every time it booted, the robot was born again, and every time it was shut down, it died.
I've misremembered the title for years as Me. It's NOT Solo or Weapon or a novelization of Short Circuit.
